# write and read file order nature android

Tags: android, file, filewriter

[developer data-storage-files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}



private String readfile(){
        String content="";
        try{
            InputStream inputStream=openFileInput(myfile);

            if(inputStream!=null){
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString="";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();

                while((receiveString=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }
                inputStream.close() ;
                content=stringBuilder.toString();

            }
        }


        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            Log.e(FILENAME1, "File Not Found"+e.toString());
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(FILENAME1,"Cannot read file"+e.toString());
        }
        return content;

    }
```

I try to write a txt file according to this website, say i want to save the data like this way: ever day i save one number after the date
line 1 2014-12-23 3
line 2 2014-12-24 6
line 3 2014-12-25 10
.
.
.
.
But for every time I write data into this file, it seems that the file is overwritten and every time i read the file, this returns me the most update number. I want to save the date and get the data on one specific line. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
outputStream = openFileOutput(filename,  Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

Also you might have to check if files exists. If it doesn't exist use your original statement and if it does exist then use the statement I have mentioned.

Comment: But my focus problem is how to save the data into line by line and read data line by line. And I assume the file is repeatedly read and write.

Comment: In that case its better to use Database. I don't think its possible to read only a specific line at one time. You  will get complete data from file.